# finding the probability of exceeding certain threshold

Tags: python, probability

I have an array of lenghth 324. I am trying to find the probability of exceeding certain threshold based on the values in the array

I have tried::

```
data = [3,4, 5, 1, 5, 8, 9] ## sample

p = 100 * (4/(len(data)+1)) ## where 4 is my threshold.
```

I am not sure if this is right and is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: If all the elements are equally likely to occur in the sequence, then you should use range of the numbers rather the length of the list.

Comment: If it is based on the values in the array then don't you need to count the number of items greater than the threshold and divide that by the array? e.g.: `100*sum(x > threshold for x in data)/len(data)`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're basing this on an unknown distribution of data, you can take the ratio between the elements that exceed your threshold and the total number of elements. Since you've tagged `numpy`, here is a solution that uses it.

```
import numpy as np

data = [3, 4, 5, 1, 5, 8, 9]
data = np.array(data)
threshold = 4
np.sum(data > threshold) / data.size
```

Output

```
0.5714285714285714
```